# Importing Module, Function, Instance

Tags: python, import, importerror

I've been running some tests learning how import works:

file1:

```
class Player():

    hp=0

    def __init__(self):
        self.hp=0

    zim = Player()
    zim.hp = 5
```

file2:

```
import test1

print(test1.zim.hp)
```

I run file2: and get an output of 5.  (wave flag of triumph)

Soooo, then I change file1 to this:

```
def Test():
    class Player():
        hp=0

        def __init__(self):
            self.hp=0

    zim = Player()
    zim.hp = 5
```

I've been trying to modify my code in file2 to get my output of 5 but its failing.  Is there a way to import a function and then instance specific data(hp in this example)?  I am aware of 'return' but was wondering if there is a way to modify the following code to import the instance I need directly.

ie: abc would be....??? O.o

```
import test1

print(abc.test1.zim.hp)
```

~T

Comment: import `test1`, what is test1?

Comment: Why did you modify the test1 file to wrap everything in the Test() function? What were you trying to achieve by doing that when it was working previously?

Comment: There is no `zim` object. The function body isn't even executed unless you explicitly call it, and when you do, you still can't reach inside the function and pull its guts out unless the function explicitly makes them available with something like `return`.

Comment: In your first version of file1, the two `zim` lines are inside your object definition. In your second version, they are outdented to be part of the `Test()` function, not the object. Could this be your problem?

Comment: I think the original version of file1 hasn't been writeen here correctly - based on the comment "I run file2: and get an output of 5. (wave flag of triumph)", I think the last 2 lines of file1 *must* be in the outermost scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question "I was wondering if there is a way to modify the following code to import the instance I need directly": No.

Just as you cannot reach into a function and grab its inner workings WITHIN a module, you can't do so in an import either.

That function has defined what a `Player` is, instantiated it, and called one of its attributes. Then the function ends, and the program has no idea what a `Player` is, much less what `zim` is and what its `hp` attribute is!

Answer (score 0):

In your `test1` you have:

```
class Player():
    hp=0
    def __init__(self):
        self.hp=0
    zim = Player()
    zim.hp = 5
```

This will throw a `NameError: name 'Player' is not defined` because you are creating an instance of `Player` when it's class definition is not over yet. I think you intend to do:

```
class Player():
    hp=0
    def __init__(self):
        self.hp=0
zim = Player()    # This and the next line are indented differently
zim.hp = 5
```

In this case `zim` becomes a module variable of `test1` and hence `zim.hp` can be printed from `test2`

Now, after you edited your `test1` to:

```
def Test():
    class Player():
        hp=0

        def __init__(self):
            self.hp=0

    zim = Player()
    zim.hp = 5
```

the `Player` object instantiation is outside it's class declaration, so it is right. But the variable `zim` exists only within the function `Test()`. When you print `zim.hp` from another module `zim` does not exist as a module variable to be accessed from `test2`.

May be you can `return zim.hp` from the `Test()` method. If you do that, you can access the value from `test2` as `print(test1.Test())`

Hope this helps.